# Careers: create PDF is not handling properly the sections Writing and Reading

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, pdf

Scenario #1: no items in the section Writing, a few items in Reading

1. click on create pdf
2. in the PDF you get your readings under the title "Writing" (should be "Reading")

Scenario #2: one item in the section Writing, a few items in Reading

1. click on create pdf
2. in the PDF you get:

   - your readings under the title "Writing" (should be "Reading"), as in scenario #1
   - there are no writings (there should be one)

Hope it to be clear. Let me know in case it isn't.

Thank you!

Comment: True, reproduced. Can't see why you split this into two scenarios though: the bug is the "Writing" section in the PDF takes the "Reading" list, and the PDF does not contain your actual "Writing" list.

Comment: When I try it, it just lumps both sections under "Writing" - nothing is missing. But I'll take a further look, and fix it by making Writing just show, y'know, writing. (I can't honestly believe anybody needs or wants Reading on there at all, but I'm open to persuasion)

Comment: @Alex good point about not needing Reading, didn't even occur to me. If it's left out by design, no need to add it.

Answer (score 1):

There were two issues here. The "Writing" section on the PDF was actually just a list of all articles on your profile - whether they were ones you'd written or just ones you'd read. And books were completely ignored!

So a book that you'd written wouldn't appear under "Writing", but all of the blog posts you'd read did. Oops.

I've now fixed this so it lists books and articles you've written.

If anybody *really* thinks it's necessary or desirable to add a "Reading" section to the PDF, just ask and we'll add it. (But really, this feels like padding to me, and I think you'd be better off if your CV just concentrated on the interesting stuff).

Comment: Thank you @alex, very quick! Actually if you allowed readings in the PDF, I'd be happy. I think it does add some value to the classic list of experiences/technologies. Thanks.

Comment: Yes please, add also read books. In real word not all people read tech books.