# Why are my books not exported when I save my Careers profile as PDF?

Tags: feature-request, support, jobs, pdf

Why are my books not exported when I save my Careers profile as PDF?

Comment: Alex addressed this [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244514/careers-create-pdf-is-not-handling-properly-the-sections-writing-and-reading/244515#244515). It's easy to add but does it add any value to the PDF export? Is this something you feel employers are looking for?

Comment: Yes,ask your coworker ,hoe many how them hace read some books about their job?

Comment: sure, we've all read lots of books but is that information that is useful to an employer? Or to other people for that matter? Feels a little like unnecessary fluff on the profile. We do export books you've written...